Docusign(esignature) implementation in React-native
Has anyone worked on any sample project of Docusign(esignature) in React-native. I wasn't able to find any support or help on internet. I tried to integrate native mobile sdk in the project but could not call the DSManager from my react-native project. It gives me an error in DSMManager file while calling the setupWithConfiguration.
So, I am not even sure if it is possible to implement docusign in react native or not.

Hi Ishika!!, did you find anything related with that? I have the same problem.

I implemented it via webview
